# How to reuse browser session in testcafe?

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, session-cookies, functional-testing, testcafe

I created automation script in testcafe, steps:
1. Login to app
2. Click on menu conversation
3. Manually, it will redirect to new page namely conversation page
But in automation, after step 2, it spawn browser so need to login again.
My question is, how to use the session to the spawn browser so that I no need to login again?

Here's my code

```
import { Selector } from 'testcafe';
import libHelper from '../../lib/helper';
require('dotenv').config();

const helper = new libHelper();

fixture `broadcast`
    .beforeEach( async t => {
        await t.getBrowserConsoleMessages()
        await helper.adminLogin()
    })

test('Make sure admin redirected to conversation page', async t => {
    await t
    .click(Selector('.nav-label').withText('Conversations'))
```

After click .nav-label it should be redirect to conversation page without relogin

Comment: What do you mean by saying 'spawn browser'? Does a new browser window appear after a click on the `.nav-label` element?
Also, you might want to take a look at the TestCafe [Role](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/authentication/user-roles.html) functionality.

Comment: yes, new browser window appear after click the element

Comment: >Manually, it will redirect to new page namely conversation page But in automation, after step 2, it spawn browser so need to login again.-> It looks like a problem with TestCafe. Could you please provide a simple example that we can run locally?

Comment: Sorry, I cant provide the link because it is company project. Manually, after conversation menu clicked, it will open new tab namely conversation page

Comment: @HerawatiManurung. 
We cannot say anything precise without a working sample. If you cannot share the link here, you can send it at support@devexpress.com.

Please note that our policy prevents us from accessing internal resources without prior written approval from a site owner. If you want us to research the problem directly on your side, please ask the website owner to send us written confirmation at support@devexpress.com. It must permit DevExpress personnel to remotely access the website and its internal resources for research/testing/and debugging purposes.

Comment: Here's the selector of the menu ````<a href="/lcv2" target="_blank">Conversations</a>````. So if I click this menu, will open new browser and need to relogin

Comment: It's difficult to find the cause of the problem without a complete example that can be run locally.
Please create an example and I will investigate this issue.